# Compress data in Java and Decompress data in C#

Tags: c#, java, compression

I'm going to send data from java to c# and I need compress data in java and decompress in c#.
Is There any same way to compress and decompress data in java to c#?
thanks

I Wrote a example in java and c#.I used  java.util.zip.GZIPOutPutStream in java to compress data and System.IO.Comperssion.GZipStream in c# to decompress data. But when in c# i got "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream" error.

In Java:

```
  encode="admin";
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(encode.getBytes().length);
      GZIPOutputStream gs = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
      gs.write(encode.getBytes());
      System.out.println("Zip "+baos.toByteArray().toString());
      gs.close();
      encode=baos.toByteArray().toString();//.toByteArray().toString();
```

}

In C#:

```
  1: var bigStream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj)),                   CompressionMode.Decompress);
            var bigStreamOut = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            byte[] b2=new byte[4096];
            bigStream.Read(b2,0,b2.Length);
            string hh1=Encoding.UTF8.GetString( bigStreamOut.GetBuffer()).Trim();
```

I got error "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream" in line 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the same thing as you did and for me it works.
The pieces of code I used is:

Java:

```
// Enjoy the horrible constructor chaining here
try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("java.gz"))))) {
    out.write("Hello world from Java 1.7!");
    // Make sure everything gets written
    out.flush();
} // Auto out.close() by using the try-catch-with-resources pattern
```

and in C#:

```
GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(new FileStream("java.gz", FileMode.Open), CompressionMode.Decompress);
// Excuse me if there was an easier way to read the strings.
int character = zip.ReadByte();
while (character != -1)
{
    Console.Write((char)character);
    character = zip.ReadByte();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The result for me was a nice message: "Hello world from Java 1.7!", which was exactly how I entered it in Java. So maybe you are giving C# the wrong file or missing some commands?

EDIT Based on your given code:
If you are using the encode to write the data into a file based on:

```
encode=baos.toByteArray().toString();//.toByteArray().toString();
```

It will output the memory-information of the object and not the actual data itself. The ToByteArray() are the bytes that you want to store in the file and not the toString() version of the byte array.

Comment: hi, thanks to replay.I implemented your code in my app and work very well but when send string from java to c# I get the "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream" error.

Comment: Could you add some code of your app in the original post so we have an idea of how you are attempting to read the gzip files?

Comment: Is it the best practice to use GZip stream for data compression and decompression between Android and C#?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checkout [zlibnet](http://zlibnet.codeplex.com/) and [jzlib](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/)